# How to prevent Fiddler from causing errors in app

Tags: android, ssl, https, fiddler

I'm trying to capture HTTPS traffic from this [mobile game](https://apps.qoo-app.com/en/app/5387?from=search:q%3DBANDAI%2BNAMCO%2BEntertainment%2BInc.%26exact%3D1%26source%3D4%26page%3D2). I'm using Nox (version 6.2.3.1) to run the app and Fiddler to capture the HTTPS traffic. However, each time I run Fiddler, the app gives me errors [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9pr.png). Running Fiddler also causes ["privacy errors" on most websites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32nIn.png).

I believe this is being caused due to me having "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" turned on. When that option is turned off, everything seems to run just fine. However, I need to have "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" turned on or I won't be able to gather the data I need, such as the base URL for the game and the files its downloading.

Is there any way to prevent these errors from occurring? I already have trusted the certificate on my computer. This did not solve my problem with the game not being able to pass the download screen and getting that error, sadly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional notes:** I'm using the latest version of Fiddler and running this on Windows 10 (64 bit). I used [this tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) to configure Fiddler for Nox.

Comment: do you install fiddler root cert into your system,if not, try install it and test to see if error disappear

Comment: @J1B I have. I also tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it. The error still appears in the game.

Comment: from your posted image, it seems most of the https links are not being decrypted , so maybe you can open a https site in IE and check if its cert is like "DO_NOT_TRUST fiddler_root", if not , then maybe there are still some errors in fiddler root install process

Comment: Note that this tutorial does not work for Apps that are developed for Android 7+. Those apps to not consider the added certificate as trusted certificate. Bypassing the certificate check requires Root, Xposed and one of the XPosed SSL unpinning and trust modules.

Comment: @Robert Tried that, still gave me the same results as before sadly.